# How to deploy MS Access 2010 database with ActiveGantt Chart control?

Tags: windows-7, ms-access-2010, gantt-chart

I'm evaluating the Boötes ActiveGantt control. The control works fine on my machine. But when I share my Access application with other colleagues they get the error message "control does not contain an object"

```
Public Function ActiveGanttVCCtl1() As ActiveGanttVCCtl
    Set ActiveGanttVCCtl1 = ActiveGanttVCCtl1A.Object   ' <= Error at this line
End Function
```

How can I deploy my Access application with this control? Do I have to run the ActiveGantt installation procedure on each client machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Version 3.1.0, you at least have to run regsvr32.exe to register AGVC.ocx in other machines.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The registration of AGVC.OCX with regsvr32.exe solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to run the ActiveGantt installation procedure on each client machine?

Either that, or create an installer that copies the required ActiveGantt components (.ocx, .dll, or whatever) to the target machine and registers them as required (assuming that the trial version allows it).